# Mouse event trigger two time in firefox when hovering on element. Lead to flicker. Is there any way to change this flicker?

Tags: jquery, mouse

HTML:

```
<ul class="navigate">  
<li>  
    <a title="Demo01" href="###">Demo01</a>  
    <ol>  
        <li><a title="Demo01Children01" href="###">Demo01Children01</a></li>  
        <li><a title="Demo01Children02" href="###">Demo01Children01</a></li>  
    </ol>  
</li>  
<li><a title="Demo02" href="###">Demo02</a></li>  
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
$("ul.navigate>li").mouseenter(function(){  
  $(this).children("a").slideDown();  
  console.log("hover");  
}).mouseleave(function(){   
  $(this).children("a").slideUp();  
  console.log("out");  
});
```

Running the html and the JS in the firefox, I see the output is "hover, out, hover" in the firefox firebug when the mouse hover every time. Actually It isn't my purpose which is only output "hover". Dose any one can help me solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason you're getting the flicker is because the `li` includes a bullet point.
As you enter from the left hand side, you hit the bullet point (trigger `in`), then the blank space (trigger `out`), then the text iteself (trigger `in` again).

If you add the following CSS to the demo:

```
li{
   list-style-type: none;
}
```

Do you find the behaviour disappears?

On another note: adding 'hover' behaviour on a moving (sliding) element is probably a really bad idea!

**[Codepen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rtgzc)** to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

Without changing your markup, I slightly modified your javascript to look like this :

```
$("ul.navigate > li").mouseenter(function(){  
    $(this).find("li").slideDown();  
    console.log("hover");  
}).mouseleave(function(){   
    $(this).find("li").slideUp();  
    console.log("out");  
});
```

A suggested, I also apply `display: none` to the children menu

**Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/C2nVz/1/**

**Note:** The demo also include `list-style-type: none`, as suggested by Ed, which causes multiple `mouseover` and `mouseleave` events.

Answer (score 0):

You are having problems because you are sliding the elements, which rapidly call the events again! Take a look [**at this**](http://jsfiddle.net/3yuhD/1/) jsfiddle, where I commented out the slidedown lines.

I suggest you tell us how you inted for your code to work(is the slidedown necessary?), then we can find a solution.

Basically I changed your code to:

```
$("ul.navigate>li").mouseenter(function()
{  
    //$(this).children("a").slideDown();  
    console.log("hover");  
}).mouseleave(function()
{   
   //$(this).children("a").slideUp();  
   console.log("out");  
});
```